# Check if a UIAlertView is showing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have a method that posts HTTP data and displays a UIAlertView if there is an error. If I have multiple HTTP post I will show multiple UIAlertView for every error.

I want to show a UIAlertView only if is not showing other UIAlertView.
How can I determine this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

On the object that calls set an ivar before invoking the show method on your UIAlertView.

```
...

if (!self.alertShowing) {
    theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:details delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
    self.alertShowing = YES;
    [theAlert show];
}

...
```

Then in your delegate method for the alert manage setting your flag ivar to no:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  ...
      self.alertShowing = NO;
}
```

If you want the alerts to show sequentially, I would post notifications to add each message to a queue and then only take a message off the queue after an alert is dismissed.

Comment: what if alert is showing but it can belong to other viewcontrollers and you don't know to each one?

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the original poster asked.  With the first part of the answer provide, it is implied that the owning viewcontroller is known, so your follow-up does not make sense.

Comment: No need to have an ivar, just check `visible` property, as in the answer below.

Comment: I checked isFirstResponder of the alert view for true, that also worked.

Comment: The visible property was not exposed at the time the original question was asked.  Feel free to vote up the later answer if it is more correct now, but two years passed between the original question and the shift to properties (including visible).

Comment: This code is not thread-safe. If multiple threads can show the alert, you should put this code in a @synchronized block, or you can have more than one alert.

Comment: Make a category on UIAlertView (now UIAlertController) that returns ![self.view isHidden] as the value of alertShowing.  If you give the alert's view a tag, that you have defined as an enum you can check that view by the tag's enum name.

Answer (score 60):

Why not just check the visible property, maintained by the UIAlertView class?

```
if (_alert) //alert is a retained property
{
    self.alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title"
                                             message:@"Your message" 
                                            delegate:self
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   otherButtonTitles:@"OK"] autorelease];
}
if (!_alert.visible)
{
    [_alert show];
}
```

Comment: From iOS9, the replaced 'UIAlertController' doesn't have the property 'visible'.

Answer (score 26):

If you can control the other alert views, check the `visible` property for each of them.

---

In iOS 6 or before, when an alert appears, it will be moved to a _UIAlertOverlayWindow. Therefore, a pretty fragile method is to iterate through all windows and check if there's any UIAlertView subviews.

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
  NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
  if ([subviews count] > 0)
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
      return YES;
}
return NO;
```

This is undocumented as it depends on internal view hierarchy, although Apple cannot complain about this. A more reliable but even more undocumented method is to check [if `[_UIAlertManager visibleAlert]` is nil](http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/_UIAlertManager.h).

These methods can't check if a UIAlertView from SpringBoard is shown.

Comment: one typo in your code "UIView* subviews = window.subviews;
" it should be NSArray* subviews = window.subviews; by the way it helped me a lot thanks.

Comment: @Deepesh, have you found solution ?

Comment: @Jacky, I am not found any right solution ... if you found any solution ... please paste your valuable answer ....Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
- (BOOL)checkAlertExist {
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
        if ([subviews count] > 0) {
            for (id cc in subviews) {
                if ([cc isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This will not work in iOS 7. The first subview could be a container. So you'd have to walk the entire possible tree.

Comment: @Womble, so have you found solution?

Answer (score 4):

Another option that works across the entire app and doesn't involve walking the view stack is to subclass `UIAlertView` to `MyUIAlertView`, add a static (class) variable `BOOL alertIsShowing`, and override the `-(void)show` selector.

In your overridden `show` selector, check the `alertIsShowing` variable. If it's `YES` then try again after a delay (use `dispatch_after` or set an `NSTimer`). If it's `NO`, go ahead and call `[super show]` and assign `YES` to `alertIsShowing`; when the alert view is hidden, set `alertIsShowing` back to `NO` (you'll need to be clever about handling the delegate).

Finally, go through and replace all `UIAlertView` instances with `MyUIAlertView`.

Comment: I like this answer (although I subclassed `UIAlertController` - if you're using both I would think you'd need to keep track of both). I did end up using a counter rather than a boolean. This way, if you attempt to show two alerts at the same time, you won't accidentally set the boolean to false if the appear/disappear methods get called out of sync from what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

```
func showAlert(withTitle title: String, message: String, viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewController.presentedViewController == nil { // Prevent multiple alerts at the same time
        let localizedTitle = NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "")
        let localizedMessage = NSLocalizedString(message, comment: "")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: localizedTitle, message: localizedMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)

        viewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: viewntroller.presentedViewController == nil did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it will work:

```
-(BOOL) doesAlertViewExist {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow isMemberOfClass:[UIWindow class]])
    {
        return NO;//AlertView does not exist on current window
    }
    return YES;//AlertView exist on current window
}
```

Comment: less code `-(BOOL) doesAlertViewExist { return ![[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow isMemberOfClass:[UIWindow class]]; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
// initialize default flag for alert... If alert is not open set isOpenAlert as NO
BOOL isAlertOpen;
isAlertOpen = NO;
if (isAlertOpen == NO) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert is Open" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay!!" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    // Now set isAlertOpen to YES
    isAlertOpen = YES;
}
else
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+ (BOOL)checkAlertExist {

    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        if ([window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes on my quest to find the UIAlertView in the view hierarchy:

I tried to loop through all of the `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows` view's recursively but couldn't find anything.

The `windows` property of `UIApplication` docs states the following:

> This property contains the UIWindow objects currently associated with
>   the app. **This list does not include windows created and managed by the
>   system**, such as the window used to display the status bar.

So this made me realize that the `UIWindow` where `UIAlertView` could be located is not even presented to us.

HOWEVER, there is also a property on `UIApplication` called `keyWindow`. Upon looping through that, I found private classes that would compose an alert view:

On iOS 7: `_UIModalItemHostingWindow`, `_UIModalItemAlertContentView`, `_UIBackdropEffectView` etc.

On iOS 8: `_UIAlertControllerActionView`, `_UIAlertControllerShadowedScrollView`, `_UIBackdropView` etc.

I could not find the `UIAlertView` that I presented, but rather, a bunch of classes that compose it internally. **So to answer the original question**, you can probably use the `keyWindow` property and see if you notice these classes, but your app could get rejected for trying to check for private classes.

For folks using, the newer, `UIAlertController` available for iOS 8 could get the reference to it using:
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController`.