# Where Does A UIAlertView Live While Not Dismissed

Tags: iphone, multithreading, subview, uialertview

Does anyone know in whose subview an active UIAlertView is located or how to find the thread in which it is running?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you dump the contents of the [windows property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/windows) and all subviews of all views you can see that the UIAlertView is in a separate window that overlays the main window.  Here I have a navbar with a viewcontroller and a tableview (I removed its subviews since they're not relevent).

```
<UIWindow: 0x411fd50; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x4120af0>>
: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x4123310; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x411f800>>
: | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x4123500; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x41232e0>>
: | : <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x4519d30; frame = (0 64; 320 416); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4519a40>>
: | : | <UITableView: 0x7808000; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x45182a0>>
: | <UINavigationBar: 0x45018b0; frame = (0 20; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x4500fe0>>
: | : <UINavigationItemView: 0x4522a20; frame = (100 8; 160 27); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4526310>>
: | : <UINavigationItemButtonView: 0x45230a0; frame = (5 7; 87 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4520260>>
<_UIAlertOverlayWindow: 0x4179b70; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4188dc0>>
: <UIAlertView: 0x4194bc0; frame = (3.8 161.95; 312.4 177.1); transform = [1.1, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; animations = { transform=<CABasicAnimation: 0x4191160>; opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x41226f0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x4144c30>>
: | <UILabel: 0x4177e70; frame = (12 15; 260 23); text = 'Name of Date'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4179370>>
: | <UILabel: 0x418b100; frame = (12 45; 260 41); text = 'Name of the date that you...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4128450>>
: | <UIThreePartButton: 0x41942a0; frame = (11 102; 262 43); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x4191f30>>
```

Here is the code that produces the dump.  I found it useful on occasion to see what is going on when something isn't doing what I expect:

```
void dumpView(UIView* aView, NSString* indent) {
    if (aView) {
        NSLog(@"%@%@", indent, aView);      // dump this view

        if (aView.subviews.count > 0) {
            NSString* subIndent = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", 
                           indent, ([indent length]/2)%2==0 ? @"| " : @": "];
            for (UIView* aSubview in aView.subviews) dumpView( aSubview, subIndent );
            [subIndent release];
        }
    }
}

void dumpWindows() {
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        dumpView(window, @"dumpView: ");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.  BTW, how did you produce the nice formatted dump?

Comment: This does the trick.  Found the idea in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528929/iphone-sdk-check-if-a-uialertview-is-showing

-(BOOL)alertIsActive
{
 for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
  if ([window.subviews count] > 0)
   if ([[window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
    return YES;
 }
 return NO;
}

Comment: @progrmr + 1 Nice sniplet. I have one question though. Is it possible to find in whose subview is the locationServices alert view? Your sniplet works for all UIAlertViews so far except the locationServices alert. Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

The active UIAlertView lives in a separate window (_UIAlertOverlayWindow). Use [`.windows` property](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW6) to find it.

The whole UI runs in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

From the problem that you describe with windows and timing, sounds like you should implement [alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548-CH3-SW1). You can trigger your followup code from within that method.

EDIT: if that did not work, I'd try doing a delay to execute the FB stuff after a delay when the window is really guaranteed to be gone.

Comment: Good idea, but I have tried that and the problem persists, even with animated = NO.