# self.view.subviews not showing buttons

Tags: objective-c, view, uiview, uibutton

I want to iterate through all of the subviews in my view, and do something for each UIButton.
This is the code i'm using (in the end of the viewDidLoad):

```
for(UIView* v in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"This is a button");
        //DO SOMETHING FOR EACH BUTTOn
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the "This is a button" line is never reached...

Why is that?

Comment: Are the buttons direct subviews or contained in another subview?

Comment: How You Add the `SubView` ?

Comment: Just thought of that - I'll try to add else if([v isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) and drilldown. Should solve the problem. I hope...

Comment: Is there a way to get all UIButtons no matter where they are?

Comment: are you adding buttons in any other view like scrollview?

Comment: where did you add buttons to view

Comment: Try using recursive function - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746478/how-can-i-loop-through-all-subviews-of-a-uiview-and-their-subviews-and-their-su

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIButton *eachButton in self.view.subviews)
{     
     [eachButton methodWhichYouNeedToAssign];
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

self.view.subviews will return only the subviews of that view.

For eg. `View A`->`View B` ->`view C`

Subviews of `View A` will list only `View B`,`View C` will be only available as the subview of `view B`

So try some recursive method to drilldown into all the subviews