# Global hook for showing UIViews

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an iOS app I'm working on using Xamarin and MVVMCross, but I am also using a third-party native library which includes some views of it's own (loaded from `.xib` files with the implementation in the library). What I need to do is set some properties on those native views and I'm trying to see if there's a way to do it that doesn't involve jumping into xcode and trying to recompile that whole thing (because I can't get that working at the moment).

So my question is, is there a way to intercept, application-wide, all attempts to load a view so that I can examine the view and if it's one of those from the third-party library, set some properties on it before it's displayed?

MvvmCross has a `MvxTouchViewPresenter` which has a `ChangePresentation` property, but it seems to only apply to `MvxViewController` loaded by MvvmCross itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily intercept all attempts to access a viewmodel by overriding the `Show()` method on your MvxTouchPresenter. For example:

```
    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        IMvxTouchView view = this.CreateViewControllerFor(request);
        UIViewController viewController = (UIViewController) view;
        this.Show(view);
    }
```

You can then examine all Views in the UIView heirarchy by using something similar to the [Objective-C code in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746478/how-can-i-loop-through-all-subviews-of-a-uiview-and-their-subviews-and-their-su). You just need to walk through all the UIViews in the viewController property and identify your view (perhaps by "smelling it" with respondsToSelector; I can't figure out exactly how you'd use isKindOfClass if Xamarin doesn't know it).

I hope I understood your question. Let me know if there's anything else missing.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking at view opened by native code, not views opened by MvvmCross. `Show` is never called because it's not a view model request.

Comment: Wow, well in that case I think you'd need to subclass the view. I think you identified that you'd need to do something like that but you can't compile some stuff in Xcode. I know there's a temptation to try to come up with a really complex technical solution to avoid what you don't want to do but I really think you're trying to solve the wrong problem in this case. Perhaps your question needs to be "Why won't X compile? I'm getting error Y."