# Objects of cell's subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to know how can I get all sub views of any `UITableview` cell. 
 So please suggest any suitable answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it : getting for tableView SubViews.

```
  int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];// Only for the 1 row with many Sections && if many Rows then //[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSections:sections];
        for (int i=0; i<sections; i++) {

            NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i] ;
            UITableViewCell *cell =[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

            NSArray *subviews = cell.contentView.subviews;//For perticular cell

                for(id element in subviews) {
                  //if ([element isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){}
                  }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray* subViews = [cell subviews];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `recursively access all the views of the cell`, check out: [view recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2746508/1014164)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cell` is your UITableViewCell

```
for(int i = 0; i < cell.contentView.subviews.count; i++)
{
     NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] class]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) 
{
   // Get all subView
   if([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) // here you can set any class name which you need to get it.
  {
      // Get specific class from subView
  }
}
```