# Export or Print Auto Layout Constraints from Storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, constraints

Is it possible to print out the constraints set up in auto layout that you create in a Storyboard?  I would like to re-create what I have done in the Storyboard in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All instances of `UIView` has a property named `constraints`. That is an `NSArray` of all the `NSLayoutConstraint`'s associated with that particular view. You could [traverse a view hierarchy recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746478/how-can-i-loop-through-all-subviews-of-a-uiview-and-their-subviews-and-their-su) from the root view and then print out the desired [layout constraint properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html).

```
// for each view in hierarchy
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in view.constraints) {
    // print what you need here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open the storyboard file in an external editor (not xCode)?
You can read it, it's just xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you need print the `view` you should find the constraints in the super view. For example:

```
         view.superview?.constraints.forEach { (constraints: NSLayoutConstraint) in
           // If you want to find some specific constrainst
            if constraints.firstItem as! NSObject == view && (constraints.firstAttribute == .centerX) {
                // Remove it.
                constraints.isActive = false
            }
        }
```

The accepted answer should only print `height` and `width` of the `view` itself.