# Finding a view of certain type within a parent

Tags: ios, swift

I use to find specific views within a parent usually like:

```
let label: UILabel? = view.subviews.filter {$0 is UILabel}.first
```

I would like to create a function that would take a type or an object of a certain type and return a view within the parent's subviews that corresponds with the type. Something along the lines of:

```
extension UIView {
    func findView(byType type: <Some Type or UIView object?>() -> UIView? {
        return self.subviews.filter {$0 is <The type>}.first
    }
}

// Usage
if let myLabel = view.findView(byType: <*UILabel.Type* or UILabel()>) { ... }
```

But I can't figure out how to do it, I tried looking up the topic, but I'm afraid my knowledge of Swift is limiting me on this one.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603570/2907715

Comment: @ielyamani No, that's not relevant at all.

Comment: It's good to learn to do this kind of stuff but instead of searching through the subviews of a view you should retain ownership of the views, either by storing them in variables when you create them or by assigning them to IBOutlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension like this :

```
extension UIView {
    func findView<T>(byType type: T.Type) -> T? {
       return self.subviews.filter {$0 is T}.first as? T
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like `view.findView(byType: UIButton.self)`

As @LeoDabus pointed out, a better extension would be :

```
func findView<T>(byType type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return subviews.first { $0 is T } as? T
}
```

Comment: This will unnecessarily loop the whole collection of subviews.  You can use collection method first where `subviews.first { $0 is T } as? T`

Comment: @LeoDabus That's a better solution. Will update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Works great, thanks. It just didn't quite make sense to me using a parameter that you don't actually use anywhere within the function. I assume you could also define the function as `findView<T>(byType _: T.Type) -> T?`?