# How to traverse through the view hierarchy of MFMessageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I want to traverse through the view hierarch of the MFMessageComposerController so that I can get the instance of UITextField where the messages are populated . Here is the code which I did in Swift for presenting MFMessageController . How can I traverse through its hierarchy?

The code :

```
@IBAction func sendSmsClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() else {
        return
    }

    let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messageVC.view.endEditing(true)
    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    NSLog("Subviews %@", messageVC.view.subviews);
   // self.view.endEditing(true)

self.present(messageVC, animated: false) {
   
}
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.rawValue) {
        case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Message failed")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Message was sent")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell how to traverse through the view hierarchy of the MFMessageViewController?

**The result of the NSLOG**

[image]

The agenda of me is to mimic the same as shown in this app. To find the textfield and to Disable the editing . The app from Appstore:

Comment: `NSLog("Subviews %@", messageVC.view.subviews);` did it work at least? Any output? I'd call maybe `loadView` to force loading. Also, Debug View Hierarchy of XCode might help too. BUT, since it's private, I wouldn't recommand doing that.

Comment: @larme I have updated the question with the output which I got from the NSLog . And yes the main agenda for me is to disable the editing of MFMessageComposer which I found in one of the App Store app.. The gif of that is attached

Comment: Well, you need to iterate again on he subviews... There are plenty of views and subviews I guess... But again, you saw it on an app, but it might be rejected for that reason too.

Comment: @Larme yes the behaviour is on multiple apps. Can you please help me on how to traverse through the views of MFMessageComposer?

Comment: You did `NSLog("Subviews %@", messageVC.view.subviews);`? Well, you have a `NSArray` of `UIView`, call `subview` on them too, etc. You can use a for loop, a while, loop, etc.

Comment: @Larme I am totally out of mind ... could you please help me with an answer of how to traverse through the UIView NSArray?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746478/how-can-i-loop-through-all-subviews-of-a-uiview-and-their-subviews-and-their-su ? That's my first found while searching. Did you try Debug View Hierarchy too? Does it work for that ViewController?

Comment: @Larme unfortunately MFMessageComposer doesn't works on Simulator and while trying to debug in iPhone device it shows error fetching debug hierarchy

Comment: You could also try [revealapp](https://revealapp.com/)