# add overlay view over all other views

Tags: iphone, uiview, overlay, superview

how do you add an overlay view that goes over everything. eg over a tab bar controller, and a navigation controller?

thanks

Comment: In the end i solved the problem by adding a button to the superview, this button I made to the size of the screen and this formed the background. I then put the progress view on top of it, and a cancel button.

This may be a bit of a naf solution but it works great

Answer (score 2):

Find the "top" view in your stack, and add a subview.  eg

```
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:myView];
```

The hardest part is finding the topmost view; with a tab bar, it will be its own view.

Answer (score 2):

Add a window.  That's what the popup keyboard and UIAlertView do, you can see that in [this view dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715534/where-does-a-uialertview-live-while-not-dismissed/2715772#2715772).

Answer (score 2):

Use a modal view controller. Have a read of this guide:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Presenting the view controller itself is easy:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                         initWithRootViewController:addController];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```