# Subviews counted in root CALayer's sublayers?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiview, calayer

I noticed today, when adding 1 CALayer and 2 subviews to my view, when I run the following code in my `UIView` instance:

```
[self.layer.sublayers count]
```

This returns `3`. Does this mean that a subview is also considered a sublayer? If I only wanted the CALayers that I've drawn in my `sublayers` call, how would i do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the hierarchy used by layers, but I did write a [function to log the hierarchy of views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715534/where-does-a-uialertview-live-while-not-dismissed/2715772#2715772).  You could modify this code to log the layer tree.  Seeing how the views and layers are nested might help you understand how it works better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each `UIView` has an underlying `CALayer` which is added to its superview's layer when the view is added to the superview.

I don't know the ideal way to find only your own layers. Since `sublayers` is an `NSArray` (as opposed to an `NSSet`), it means it's an ordered list, which means you can be sure that the order in which you add views to the superview is the same order they will appear in said array.

Thus, if you add your UIViews first, and then add your own drawn CALayers afterwards, you can probably get your own by accessing the objects starting at index 2 (skipping 0 and 1) in `sublayers`.

Of course, if you then add or remove views to the superview you'd have to modify this value, so presuming this actually works, you'll want to somehow dynamically generate it.

You can ascertain the index for a layer as you add it, using `indexOfObject:` on the `sublayers` property. A safer route might be to simply store this index somewhere in a list and to access the sublayers with indices from that list only.

Answer (score 1):

> If I only wanted the CALayers that I've drawn in my sublayers call,
>   how would i do that?

You can do this by making the view that is currently a subview of `self` into a sibling view by having them both be subviews on a containing view.  Then your current `self.layer.sublayers` would just contain the CALayers you added manually.

One way to think about it is that *it is the layer hierarchy,* not the *view hierarchy* which defines the render hierarchy.  The view hierarchy is just a wrapper to handle interactivity that UIView adds to its underlying CALayer graphics.  Thus, when you add a subview to a view, it simultaneously, though in some sense independently, adds its layer as a sublayer to the view's layer.  You could probably override this functionality in a subclass or category on UIView...

Answer (score 1):

From the CALayer documentation:

> **delegate**
>
> Specifies the receiver’s delegate object.
>
> @property(assign) id delegate
>
> **Discussion**
>
> In iOS, if the layer is associated with a UIView object, this property must be set to the view that owns the layer.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in OS X v10.5 and later.
>
> Related Sample Code