# UINavigationBar custom title being hidden by background

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am adding a custom `UIImageView` to my `UINavigationBar` using this code:

```
UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)] autorelease];
[background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_background.png"]];
[background setTag:kTagForReference];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:background atIndex:0];
```

I then add a custom title using this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44)];
... 
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:label];
[label release];
```

But on some of my pushed views the title is being hidden (or isn't visible). I can't seem to push more than two views onto the stack without the title disappearing.

I've tried to force my `UIImageView` background to the back of the bar but that still doesn't help. I've printed the subviews of the `UINavigationBar` and I can see that the UILabel is there, I just can't see it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the [dumpWindows() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715534/where-does-a-uialertview-live-while-not-dismissed/2715772#2715772), the output would show the view hierarchy so you can see what view is covering it up.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use a `UIToolBar` instead of a `NavigationBar`. Then you can add the subviews to the `UIToolbar`.

Bring the UILabel to the front most view.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: label];
```

Comment: If I used a `UIToolbar`, then what would happen to all my navigation stack?

Comment: As long as you add the UIToolbar to your controller, and just hide the NavigationBar, absolutely nothing. You can even setup a "Back" or "Done" button to either pop or dismiss said navigationController.