# How do I get ALL views active?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uikit, uiwindow

When I am listing recursively all subviews starting from window (from `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` iterating over all subviews of a view), I do not get all views of my application.

When I assign tags to buttons on toolbars or navigation bars within the Interface Builder, I cannot find these with the `viewWithTag:` method (starting from window or a view instance). But I do find a tagged toolbar or navigation bar most of the time...

When I go back programmatically from buttons, toolbars, etc. calling superview, I very often do not get back to window.

Is there a way to find all views active within an application?

Comment: There is code for that in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715772/154803)

Comment: @progrmr nice little snippet - thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code snippet. But this does not solve the problem. Acutally, I had used a similar code to get all subviews.

Comment: If you create a view with the Interface Builder and add a toolbar with buttons, you will not get the button views nor the toolbar! If you create a navigation bar, you will get the navigation bar in the listing, but I am not sure, if it is the correct instance. Because, if you assign in IB a tag number to the navigation bar, the navigation bar listed will have a tag with value 0!

Answer (score 0):

To get all views, **you have to wait** until all views are created. And this takes some time.

I called in `viewDidLoad` my dumping function like `[self displayViews]`, and got only a part of the views (because the rest was not created yet).

The correct way to get all views is to call `performSelector`, because this **queues the request** within the same threat, but does wait a little bit:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayViews) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

Remark: Tags assigned to toolbar buttons in the Interface Builder won't show up, because buttons are coded somehow differently, that means, buttons do show up, but do have tag values of `0`.