# Find UIAlertView without having reference to it iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I was using a code snippet in my project answered here: [UIAlertView without having reference to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579821/find-uialertview-without-having-reference-to-it)

Here's the code:

```
+ (UIAlertView *) getUIAlertViewIfShown {
    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] == 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    if ([window.subviews count] > 0) {
        UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
            return (UIAlertView *) view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Unfortunately its not working in iOS 7 and I'm unable to dismiss an alert view. While debugging I found that in the loop its showing that view is of class `UITransitionView`. Pretty confusing because I couldn't find any quick documentation for this view class.

Any ideas how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just keep a reference to it.

Comment: Is it possible there are more windows? You are only checking one window. Why not check all of them?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using a Macro for showing alert views and is used too frequently. Your suggestion will be last option.

Comment: @rmaddy I debugged the code and its returning only one object in the array for windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In iOS7, the `UIAlertView` window does not appear in `-[UIApplication windows]`.  In fact, the `UIAlertView` itself is never added to any window, `-[UIAlertView window]` is always `nil`.  Instead, the alert view manages a variety of undocumented views placed in `-[UIApplication keyWindow]` with no reference back to the alert view.

Your only real option in iOS7 is to actually keep track of your alert views.

Comment: I modified all my code and kept reference to alert views and now they are working fine.

Comment: the window for UIAlertView is -UIModalItemHostingWindow(Private API)

Answer (score 15):

iOS 7 solution

```
Class UIAlertManager = objc_getClass("_UIAlertManager");
UIAlertView *topMostAlert = [UIAlertManager performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];
```

I am not sure if it is approvable by AppStore, but works

UPD single line code:

```
UIAlertView *topMostAlert = [NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager") performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];
```

Comment: Is it ok if I used NSClassFromString instead of objc_getClass ?

Comment: Does this get through review?

Comment: Is is allowed by Apple? @TùngĐỗ

Comment: Is it allowed by Apple? Please tell us. @TùngĐỗ

Comment: Of course this is not allowed in production.  For Integration Testing it might have been helpful, but on the simulator it doesn't seem to work.  Maybe 7.1 killed this.

Comment: It doesn't work i get the error references non-public API on uploading to appstore.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue and in my case alerts are displayed from different instance of view controller, As Brian has already mentioned that `UIAlertView` window does not appear in -`[UIApplication windows]` in iOS7.

So to keep track of this following approach can be followed -

1. Define a `BOOL` constant in App Delegate -

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAlertVisibleOnAppWindow;
   ```
2. Where 'UIAlerView` is present, check earlier instance existence -

   ```
   AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   if (!delegate.isAlertVisibleOnAppWindow) {
       delegate.isAlertVisibleOnAppWindow = YES;

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init…//alert init code

       // Either handle alert cancel/completeion click here via blocks, or use alert delegates to reset the isAlertVisibleOnAppWindow BOOL variable to NO.
   }
   ```

This might be helpful to some other people, thought of sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *topMostAlert = [NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager") performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];
```

This will NOT be allowed to publish into Apple Store. During build validation Xcode will throw an error, something like: "access to undocumented method.."
So you can't use it, however this code works well.

Comment: It doesn't work i get the error references non-public API on uploading to appstore.

Comment: perfect way... if you dont want to upload your app on App Store

Answer (score 0):

You can register to `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(aWindowBecameVisible:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and in aWindowBecameVisible check the window description for `_UIModalItemHostingWin`:

```
if ([[theWindow description] hasPrefix:@"<_UIModalItemHostingWin"])
{
    // This is the alert window
}
```