# Check if UIView is displaying a UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uialertview, subview

Is it possible to determine if the current UIView has a UIAlertView on display (other than setting a variable every time a UIAlertView is created).

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
    if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:UIAlertView]) { ... }
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528929/iphone-sdk-check-if-a-uialertview-is-showing

Comment: Similar, but the accepted answer is no good for me since I have so many instantiations, and the alternative answer is to use an undocumented method... I guess there is no quick and easy way

Comment: Do you just want to know that an alert is shown or do you care where it originated from?

Comment: Just want to know if one is currently visible. Or at least that one has been displayed, as I can set an iVar to TRUE once it has been dismissed. I just don't want to set the iVar in every instance of showing an alert.

Comment: can I ask what interaction scenario you are trying to create?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This will not work in iOS7 and above.**

<strike>**[alertView Show]** adds subview on main window I guess.</strike>

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows){
    for (UIView *subView in [window subviews]){
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
            NSLog(@"has AlertView");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"No AlertView");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is closest to what I'm trying to achieve, so I'll give it the answer, although for some reason it didn't really work, as I'm not sure the UIAlertView remains in the subviews after it's been displayed, even though it remains on the screen.

Comment: I tried this one and for some reason it doesn't work. But I found another answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2529692/1091926 and it works for me. Codes look similar though. (I guess its because of "if ([subviews count] > 0)")

Comment: Actually I believe it works because of the [subviews objectAtIndex:0]

Answer (score 10):

I think it will work:

```
-(BOOL) doesAlertViewExist 
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow isMemberOfClass:[UIWindow class]])
    {
        return NO;//AlertView does not exist on current window
    }
    return YES;//AlertView exist on current window
}
```

Comment: Although this will technically work, it opens up the potential to introduce a bug if a non UIAlertView window is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the UIAlertView as a property on the view controller that is displaying it and then run your code:

```
if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:self.myalertview]) { ... }
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to avoid having to customise every alert view that I display since there are a lot of them.