# Can i check if any UIAlertView displaying right now?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can I in any part of my iOS application check if any UIAlertView displaying right now? I found this code

```
[NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager") performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)]
```

but it is private API and my app could be rejected by Apple.
Are there any legal ways to do this?

Comment: Check this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10727957/2298998)

Comment: It is a private API but somewhere I read that using performselector is ok with Apple's static code analysis. But you need to be double sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For devices less than iOS 7 :-**

When you make the body of the `UIAlertView` , the `[alertView Show]` adds a subview on the main window. So to detect the `UIAlertView` you simply have to check for the subviews of the current `UIView` as `UIAlertView` inherits from `UIView`.

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows){
    for (UIView *subView in [window subviews]){
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
            NSLog(@"AlertView is Present");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"AlertView Not Available");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:- For devices using iOS 7**

```
Class UIAlertManager = objc_getClass("_UIAlertManager");
UIAlertView *Alert = [UIAlertManager performSelector:@selector(Alert)];
```

and

```
UIAlertView *Alert = [NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager") performSelector:@selector(Alert)];
```

**NOTE :-** If you cannot use third party API's then your only real option in iOS7 is to actually keep track of your alert views.

Comment: Thank you. Brute force, but it's working.

Comment: Did you try it? I try just now and it don't working. Always "AlertView Not Available".

Comment: It will not work on ios7 devices. Because in ios7 devices keywindow is  being used.

Comment: This works but I think you should keep references to your alert views...

Comment: your edited answer is pointing to use private API which is asked in the question.

Comment: @TapasPal Well I have mentioned that he should keep references to his alert views

Comment: @IronManGill It's not possible to keep references to all alerts. Some alerts called by third libraries, some by StoreKit. Are there any legal way check any alerts exist in iOS7?

Comment: @Padavan If you cannot use third party API's then your only real option in iOS7 is to actually keep track of your alert views.

Answer (score 1):

you can check like this.

```
-(BOOL) doesAlertViewExist {
  for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
    NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
    if ([subviews count] > 0) {

      BOOL alert = [[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]];
      BOOL action = [[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]];

      if (alert || action)
        return YES;
     }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work on iOS 7 onwards. Is there any other way for iOS 7 onwards?