# UIAlertView show() behavior for UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

In previous versions of iOS I was able to call `show` on a UIAlertView in the App Delegate. More specifically, `show` was called in:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
```

Since `UIAlertView`s disregarded the view hierarchy in most cases, this solution worked no matter where the user was in the app.

With the introduction of `UIAlertController` this problem becomes a little trickier. `UIAlertController` is now a subclass of `UIViewController` and needs to be presented just like any other UIViewController. While presenting the UIAlertController from the keyWindow's rootViewController works, it's not the ideal solution.

Does anyone have any ideas on replicating `[UIAlertView show]` functionality for a `UIAlertController`? Any way to show the `UIAlertController` on app active without traversing the view hierarchy?

Comment: Why would you present it from the app delegate in the first place?

Comment: Could you create a custom UIAlertController class  method for `show` with a parameter that passes UIViewController? Then call that method from any view controller and pass `self`.

Comment: @vikingosegundo For this specific use case, we do an update check every time the app opens. We do not what `UIViewController` is showing without traversing the view hierarchy, so simply using `UIAlertView show` worked well.

Comment: Why not the let the rootviewcontroller do that?

Comment: @remus I could, but I still need to know which `UIViewController` is visible in order to pass the correct one.

Comment: @DylanBettermann, why would not call a UIAlertView not from the visible view controller?

Comment: @vikingosegundo That's what I'm doing, but it doesn't work if the rootViewController is not presented.

Comment: @DylanBettermann then I'd suggest using a combination of NSNotifications and ^ method to deal with when the rootVC isn't present.

Comment: present it from rootViewController if you really do not care about UX or it's appropriate for your kind of app.

Comment: @Andy The app is not distributed through the App Store and therefore has no automatic update mechanism. I don't see how that relates to not caring about UX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to present UIAlertController when not in a view controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller)

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a solution that I believe to be more elegant than the answer I posted previously. I'll copy and paste the answer I posted to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller/30508244#30508244). Follow the link at the bottom of my post if you just want to see the code.

The solution is to use an additional UIWindow.

When you want to display your UIAlertController:

1. Make your window the key and visible window (`window.makeKeyAndVisible()`)
2. Just use a plain UIViewController instance as the rootViewController of the new window. (`window.rootViewController = UIViewController()`)
3. Present your UIAlertController on your window's rootViewController

A couple things to note:

- Your UIWindow must be strongly referenced. If it's not strongly referenced it will never appear (because it is released). I recommend using a property, but I've also had success with an [associated object](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/).
- To ensure that the window appears above everything else (including system UIAlertControllers), I set the windowLevel. (`window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1`)

Lastly, I have a completed implementation if you just want to look at that.

https://github.com/dbettermann/DBAlertController

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
public class func visibleViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    return self.visibleViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?)
}

private class func visibleViewController(viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    if viewController?.presentedViewController == nil {
        println("Visible view controller: \(viewController)")
        return viewController
    } else if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        return self.visibleViewController(navigationController.topViewController)
    } else if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        return self.visibleViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
    } else {
        return self.visibleViewController(viewController?.presentedViewController)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"title"
                                  message:@" Your message hear"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *okBtnAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        //Do what action u want.
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [alert addAction:okAction];

     UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            //do something when click button
        }];
        [alert addAction:Action];

    UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [JSAlertView](https://github.com/sspbond007/JSAlertView) which handles both UIAlertView and UIAlertController APIs. 
It provides short and easy methods for displaying alerts and handles multiple alerts fired at same time, very well.