# Present UIAlertController in the currently active UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alert

I've got a timer showing an alert when finished.
This alert view should be presented in the view controller which the user is currently in.

My feeling is this could be accomplished much more effective than the following:

The way I'm doing this now is give an observer for a notification to each of my 5 view controllers as well as a method to create and present that alert.

Is there a way to only set up the alert once and then present it in the view controller that is currently active?

Here's my code:

```
// I've got the following in each of my view controllers.

// In viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SonglistViewController.presentSleepTimerFinishedAlert(_:)), name: "presentSleepTimerFinishedAlert", object: nil)
}


func presentTimerFinishedAlert(notification: NSNotification) {
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Timer finished", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
  presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Top `ViewController` on the navigation stack and directly present the `AlertController` from there. You can use the extension method posted here to find the Top `ViewController` from anywhere in your application:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30858591/2754727

Answer (score 6):

```
extension UIApplication {
    /// The top most view controller
    static var topMostViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.visibleViewController
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    /// The visible view controller from a given view controller
    var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigationController.topViewController?.visibleViewController
        } else if let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tabBarController.selectedViewController?.visibleViewController
        } else if let presentedViewController = presentedViewController {
            return presentedViewController.visibleViewController
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can easily present your alert like so

```
UIApplication.topMostViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

One thing to note is that if there's a UIAlertController currently being displayed, `UIApplication.topMostViewController` will return a `UIAlertController`. Presenting on top of a `UIAlertController` has weird behavior and should be avoided. As such, you should either manually check that `!(UIApplication.topMostViewController is UIAlertController)` before presenting, or add an `else if` case to return nil if `self is UIAlertController`

```
extension UIViewController {
    /// The visible view controller from a given view controller
    var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigationController.topViewController?.visibleViewController
        } else if let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tabBarController.selectedViewController?.visibleViewController
        } else if let presentedViewController = presentedViewController {
            return presentedViewController.visibleViewController
        } else if self is UIAlertController {
            return nil
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your navigation schema.
First of all you will need current VC. If you've got root view controller as navigation controller and don't show any modals you can get current VC from rootVC. If you've got mixed navigation. i.e. tabbar and then navigation controllers inside, with possible some modals form them you can write an extension on AppDelegate which will search and return current VC.

Now you should pin somewhere this timer class - it may be a singleton or just be pinned somewhere. Than in this timer class, when the timer ends you can look for current VC (using AppDelegate's extension method or referring to your root navigation controller) an present an alert on it.