# Dismiss and Present View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Hi I'm trying to present a viewcontroller and dismiss my current modal view but this code is not working

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController")
    self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

vice versa is not working too on completion block of presentviewcontroller

EDIT: replaced vc! to self

Comment: try with self.parentViewController?.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @SandeepKumar it's still not working

Comment: Are you trying to present first or dismiss first?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to get the viewController which presented self (current ViewController). If that view controller is rootViewController, then you can use the code below, if not then query it based on your view controller hierarchy.

```
if let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3") as? ViewController3 {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!.present(vc3, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thanks! your code works well and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller aswell

Answer (score 8):

you can't do that because when the UIViewController A calls the UIViewController B and the first controller is dismissed then the two controllers are nil.

You need to have a UIViewController as a base, in this case MainViewController is the base. You need to use a protocol to call the navigation between controllers.

you can do using protocol let say for example as bellow:-

In to your  viewController setting Protocol :

```
    protocol FirstViewControllerProtocol {
    func dismissViewController()
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate:FirstViewControllerProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
            self.delegate!.dismissViewController()
        }
    }
```

Now in your main view controller

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerProtocol {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func goToFirstViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(FirstViewController)) as! FirstViewController
    viewController.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



//MARK: Protocol
func dismissViewController() {
    if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(SecondViewController)){
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[Code example with storyboard:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6IeG934k7w0TWt5bFdGZjY4R2s/view?usp=sharing)

---

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a mistake in your code where 'self' should be the presenting view controller to present 'vc', not 'vc' its self

Your code

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController")
                vc!.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
```

Try this

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController")
                self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
```

hope this is helpful

Comment: Do you check whether somehow vc is nil. Just in case to make sure everything is OK, then we are able to trace the issue.

Comment: it's not nil and my code now is let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController") as! OrderViewController

Answer (score 3):

```
let parent = self.parentViewController!

parent.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController")
            parent.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Swift3

To present the ViewController

```
let NotificationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as! ExecutiveNotificationViewController

self.present(NotificationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To dismiss the ViewController:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```