# how can i show specific viewcontroler in notification action?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

how can i show specific viewcontroler in notification action?
in appdelegate

```
func usernotificationcenter(_center: UNUserNotification,didReceive response: UNNotificationPesponse,withCompletionHalndler completion Handler: @escaping () -> Void){ 

   if identifer == "SHOWVIEW_ACTION":
                //I want show specific viewController at this

   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss and Present View Controller in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771001/dismiss-and-present-view-controller-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func redirectToSpecificVC() {
let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "versesVC") as UIViewController
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()}
```

used these function redirect to specific view controller

Comment: instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "versesVC")
what is versecvc? storyboard id? or restoratioin id?

Comment: It's storyboard id

Comment: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'alarmRing' in bundle NSBundl
what is wrong?? i did enter alarmRing at Storyboard Id

Answer (score 0):

Add these Lines of code in did receive response, it worked for me

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifierName") as? YourViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: false)
var presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController
        while (presentedVC!.presentedViewController != nil)  {
            presentedVC = presentedVC!.presentedViewController
        }
```