# Cannot present/push another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

> Warning: Attempt to present iChat.ChatMessagesController: 0x7fee42679fd0> on iChat.NewMessageController: 0x7fee42529e60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

i have tableview that is created programmatically and other view in storyboard that iam trying to present from selected a row from the table view.

Class : ChatMessagesController

Storyboard ID ChatMessagesController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatMessagesController") as! ChatMessagesController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss and Present View Controller in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771001/dismiss-and-present-view-controller-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatMessagesController") as! ChatMessagesController
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

as this `dismiss(animated: true) {` will dismiss the current vc , and you'll not be able to present anything inside it , if you need to completely remove the current vc and replace with the new one , then do

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController  = newViewController
```

**EdiT**: You can use push and remove the current vc with ( current should be embedded in a navigation )

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController([newViewController], animated: true)
```

instead of `present`

Comment: can i dissmis the view after the newviewload ?