# NSNotification for all views at once

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to `addObserver` to all my views, when I start my application.
When there is a post coming I want to display a Modal View on top of the current `ViewController`.

Is there a way to install it directly on every View or do I need to do the

```
viewWillAppear : add
viewDidDisappear : remove
```

workaround each time ?

Comment: You could make all your UIViewController inherits from a UIViewController that will add/remove the observing and even show the modal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could have created one superclass for all you view controllers and override viewWillAppear/viewDidDisappear there.
2. If there is no exception and you want to present a modal view controller no matter what view controller is currently on screen, you can present it over self.window.rootViewController in AppDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: You can also swizzle `viewDidAppear:` and/or `viewWillDisappear:`. I'd probably use option 1 myself, but it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Create parent class like this and subclass all other classes

```
import UIKit

class TemplateClassVC: UIViewController {


override func viewWillAppear() {
}

override func viewDidDisappear() {
}


}
```

and find top viewcontroller like this
[Get top most UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller)