# Swift Present View Controller From Another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I currently have the following function inside of my main view controller (View Controller A).

```
func myAction() {       
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let viewControllerC : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerC") as UIViewController

    self.present(viewControllerC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

When `View Controller A` is currently displayed and `myAction` is called it works fine and displays `viewControllerC`.

But this function `myAction` can be called basically at any time. Sometimes even when `View Controller A` is not the current view controller on the screen. Sometimes when `View Controller B` is displayed this function still gets called. It gets called fine. But it doesn't load `viewControllerC` in that case.

I've also tried the following thinking that would display from whatever the active view controller is. But that didn't work either.

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewControllerC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

How can I get it to display `viewControllerC` when `myAction` is called no matter what view controller is currently being displayed?

Comment: A lot of ideas here about getting the top view controller (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: @danh Perfect! I used the accepted answer and that seems to work! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You presented one View Controller already and want to present second View Controller from presented View Controller, for this purpose you must call this:

`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the top viewController that are currently visible in application for getting top viewController
Use this code

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topView(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Comment: you can create a newClass name UIApplication+Extension and put the code in it.. you can call that method throughout the application.
Eg.  UIApplication.topView()

Comment: Does that answer resolve your problem with efficient way ?

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to test this. I've been using the accepted answer from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller). I plan to test this out soon and if it works I'll be sure to up vote and accept, since it seems like a better solution then the other solution I'm using now.