# How to identify the viewController a button has been added onto?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I want to know what was the name of the viewController the the button was tapped. I've already looked into the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30858591/5175709). But I believe won't work if I have different containerViews on the screen...where the viewController for each button may be different. Hence I need a different solution.

So I wrote this function to recursively look until it finds a `UIViewController`.

```
extension UIView{
    func getTypeOfMyViewController() -> UIViewController.Type?{
        if let _super = superview as? UIViewController{ // logically wrong!
            return type(of:_super)
        }else if let _super = superview{
            return _super.getTypeOfMyViewController()
        }else{
            assertionFailure("everything should end up being on some viewController")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is this line:

```
if let _super = superview as? UIViewController{
```

It gives me the following warning:

> Cast from 'UIView?' to unrelated type 'UIViewController' always fails

`superview` is a `UIView` and I don't know how to extract the **'viewController' which contains the 'view'**.

**Question1:** So How can I do that?

Additionally I would like to use the `getTypeOfMyViewController` function as such:

```
extension UIButton{
    open override var accessibilityLabel: String?{
        get {
            return "\(getTypeOfMyViewController.self): \(titleLabel?.text ?? "Null")"
        }
        set{
            // nothing particular
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing this because I want to create a unique identifier for all button taps in my logging system.

**Question2:** Does Swift offer any easier solution to this?

Comment: You could probably go up the responder chain until you hit a view controller.  Not sure if that works in 100% of cases.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-the-view-controller-responsible-for-a-view

Comment: @MartinR thanks. Is my `assertionFailure` meaningful? I mean is there ever a chance that something won't be on a viewController?

Comment: @Honey `extension UIView {
    var viewController: UIViewController? {
        return next as? UIViewController ?? (next as? UIView)?.viewController
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view controller is not a view, so it can never be a superview. You have the right idea, but you're looking at the wrong hierarchy. What you want is not the view hierarchy but the *responder chain*.

Walk up the responder chain until you come to the view controller:

```
var r : UIResponder = theButton
repeat { r = r.next! } while !(r is UIViewController)
let vc = r as! UIViewController
```