# Present a View Controller from class NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

How can I present a View Controller from the class above after I buy an in-app purchase product?

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class IAPService: NSObject {

    private override init() {}
    static let shared = IAPService()

    var products = [SKProduct]()
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

 //......some more IAP code here...
func presentVC(){ What to write here??? }
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30858591/4763963

Answer (score 0):

Since a subclass of **NSObject** has no navigation capability , you need to either

1- Use a delegate by adding this var

```
weak var myController:VCName?
```

and init it whenever you want ( before the usage so the navigation will function )  then use

```
myController?.present(anotherVC,animated:true)
```

2- Use Application's rootVC ( but note it may be presenting another vc at that time so it may/not function as this depends on your navigation structure )

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present..........
```