# swift - How to detect from what ViewController application enter background?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

In my swift app I need to know from what screen my application entered background. Im trying to use `NotificationCenter` this way:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController{
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackgroundMain), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func appMovedToBackgroundMain() {
        print("main - App moved to Background!")
    }
}

class InitViewController: UIViewController{
       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
            notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackgroundInit), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func appMovedToBackgroundInit() {
            print("init - App moved to Background!")
        }
    }
```

and when I'm press `Home` button at the `MainViewController` I got in Xcode's console these lines:

```
init - App moved to Background!
main - App moved to Background!
```

and I expected only one line there - `main - App moved to Background!`. How can I reach this?

Comment: Just remove the observer that is not in use. After the  Init View is done it should remove the observer. You'll end up with only Main view added as an observer. Voila!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On AppDelegate Methods: `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`, you can get the top most UIViewController. It is well explained on this question: [Get top most UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function:

```
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Here you can check which controller is on the top in your navigation controller's controller.

```
print(self.navigationController.topViewController)
```

Comment: should I put this function to AppDelegate? then I have an error that AppDelegate has no NavigationController and I still don't know what ViewController was at the screen

Comment: Yes put it in App Delegate

Comment: then I have an error that AppDelegate has no NavigationController and I still don't know what ViewController was at the screen

Comment: What is your navigation stack? How you are loading controllers?

Comment: Is there any navigation controller which you are using in App Delegate then use that instance.

Comment: I have `TabBar` with `NavigationController` on each tab, and at `AppDelegate` don't declare any `NavigationController`

Answer (score -2):

When application enter in background state below method will call.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Comment: function `applicationWillEnterForeground ` belongs to UIApplicationDelegate and it is not accessible from ViewController