# Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController:> on <App name:> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, alert

I'm getting this error because of I'm presenting alert in another VC, but how to solve this.

My code is :

```
{
     let message = res[0]["message"] as! String
     //If session expaired move to login page
     if message == "Session Expired" {
         //Session Expired
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             //Remove all navigations
             self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAll()
             //Check whether the user logined or not
             UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
             //Clear user defaults
             SharedClass.sharedInstance.clearDataFromUserDefaults()

             let lvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LVC") as! LoginViewController
             let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
             appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = lvc
         }
     }
     //Call alert function
     self.showAlert(title: "", msg: message)
 }
```

Alert function :

```
//Alert function
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

How to present alert properly in my case....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try presenting `alertController` on `rootViewController` as,

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The `viewController` you are calling `showAlert` method on is not currently presented `viewController` in the `view` hierarchy so either you should get the latest presented `viewController` in the `view` hierarchy or try presenting on the `rootViewController`.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller) to get the currently presented `viewController`.

Comment: Dear bro here I'm presenting same alert for entire project For ex. if TextFiled is empty please enter Textfield like. Is it ok...

Comment: Because of here we are presenting in root VC

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

or

```
 self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([LoginViewController], animated: true)
```

instead of

`self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAll()`

Comment: actually here loginVC is not my root VC , dashboard VC in root VC. So I want to make Login VC as root vc. Then if I write this code`self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)`  it will work. Am I right....

Comment: yes, or you can do something like  self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [LoginViewController]

Comment: What is the meaning of this self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [LogoinViewControllre]

Comment: Error: `Cannot assign value of type '[LoginViewController].Type' to type '[UIViewController]'`

Comment: sorry, the idea is to change the root view controller, I edit my answer with the right code

Comment: Again it's getting `Cannot convert value of type '[LoginViewController].Type' to expected argument type '[UIViewController]'`

Comment: LoginViewControoler should be an instance of your view controller that should be presented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196959/discussion-between-ios-and-m1sh0).