# push to the nextViewcontroller from popUp is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewcontroller` that presents a popUpView with two buttons, cancel and continue respectively.. but the problem is that when I press the continue button, `UINavigationController` is not pushing to the next `UIViewcontroller`.. .

-- onNextButtonTapped:

```
 @IBAction func onOkayButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC") as! NextViewController
           // let nextVCNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextVC)
           //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVCNav, animated: true)

            
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        })
    }
```

Did miss something?

Comment: are you getting self == nil

Comment: @vijeesh, oddly, nope.. nothing happens..

Comment: but, `print` messages work tho.. .

Comment: please print self and see it is nil or not

Comment: @vijeesh, it works.. self is there..

Comment: but not pushing the nextVC

Comment: can you try removing self.dismiss and directly navigate to the nextVC?

Comment: @IBAction func onOkayButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC") as! NextViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }

like this

Comment: When you dismiss your current screen self is the current screen but actually, this screen is dismissed so, first find the topmost controller and push your controller on this. To find the topmost controller: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788567/14733292. Or you can also use closure and protocol.

Comment: @vijeesh, I have tried that too, did not work.. . and `self.navigationController` prints `nil` now.

Comment: self is your popoverview or a view controller?

Comment: @vijeesh from the presented controller you can not directly navigate to the nextVC because the presented controller does not have navigation. For this, you need to present with a navigation controller.

Comment: @RajaKishan Okeye, so he can create a delegate back to the VC and perform the navigation right?

Comment: @vijeesh `self` is the viewcontroller

Comment: @RajaKishan, I did that too, still not working.. . .

Comment: @dumbDev please add more code, it will be helpful

Comment: @vijeesh. yes, you can create a delegate also use closure for alternative.

Comment: @dumbDev please first debug your code. First, check whether your back controller has navigation or not. And check which controller returns from the top controller function and check returns controller has navigation or not.

Comment: For topmost controller use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301729/14733292

Comment: @dumbDev Did you try tap on the screen? Because when push method is not called on main thread it's a common issue.

Comment: If understand correctly you are presenting a view from a ViewController but you can't push anything from that view, you should use a delegation pattern. Can you please post the relevant code from which you present the view?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a controller chain issue. As from what I understand you must have presented the popup modally and by doing that you have moved out of the `UINavigationController` stack. So pushing a view from popupview controller is not an option. You can:

1. Create a protocol, (or block implementation) that inform `viewcontroller` which presented popup, that particular button was clicked (something similar to UIAlertController)
2. Make a popup as a view inside view controller and show and hide that with animation. That was you can add the action of the button of this popup to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UINavigationController is not in hierarchy.
Try this

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
nav.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```