# SwiftUI how to hide navigation bar with TabView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI `TabView` inside `NavigationView`, But I just can't hide the navigation bar in iOS 13.0 simulator.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                TabView(selection: .constant(0),
                        content: {
                            TestView()
                                .tabItem { Text("test") }
                                .tag(0)
                                .navigationBarTitle("")
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                        })
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }

}
```

Any help? thanks!

[image]

Comment: I have same issue in iOS15

Comment: any solutions found?

Answer (score 5):

Check this

```
TabView {
        ECHomeView().tabItem {
            VStack {
                Text("Home")
                Image.Home.renderingMode(.template)
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
        ECMyClaimsView().tabItem {
            VStack {
                Text("My Claims")
                Image.Myclaims.renderingMode(.template)
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")
        ECAddClaimView().tabItem {
            VStack {
                Text("Create")
                Image.Create.renderingMode(.template)
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")
        ECMyApprovalsView().tabItem {
            VStack {
                Text("My Approvals")
                Image.MyApprovals.renderingMode(.template)
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")
        ECMenuView().tabItem {
            VStack {
                Text("Menu")
                Image.Menu.renderingMode(.template)
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, it did work for me but I am having an issue and need your help in that. I am using navigation link to reach the *tab view** screen and when I reach the *tabview* screen, it is still getting the top space but if I **directly opens** the tab view your *solution* works fine. So, can you tell any solution in which if someone is coming from a different view to tab view, it should not take the top space

Comment: This works on the first display tab, switch tab and top spaces displayed. I think we should use a custom tab view. I tried many ways but not work.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.Even though I decorated each View with `.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")`, the top space was not hidden when I moved from another View to TabView on iOS 15 series.

So I tried the following method, and the top space is hidden correctly even when moving from another View to TabView.

The following is a simple sample.

```
@State var selectedTab: TestTab = .test1
@State var test1ViewNavigationBarHidden = false
@State var opacity = 0.0

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Test1View()
                    .navigationBarHidden(test1ViewNavigationBarHidden)
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .onAppear{
                        Task {
                            try! await Task.sleep(seconds: UInt64(0.001))
                            test1ViewNavigationBarHidden = true
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(TestTab.test1)

                Test2View()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")
                    .tag(TestTab.test2)

                Test3View()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("")
                    .tag(TestTab.test3)
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
    .opacity(opacity)
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
            opacity = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

`.navigationBarHidden(false)` was applied to the first view of the TabView, and after a delay, it was set to true.

Since it flickers for a moment when it is displayed, it will be displayed nicely if you use Animation when displaying the RootView.

It may seem a bit aggressive, but it works fine in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's system bug.
I had same problem.

[image: Same issue]

Here is my Solution

#### 1. Add `UIApplication` extension

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30858591/12496427

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

#### 2. Using it in `onAppear()` function

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Text("Hello")
        }
/////// HERE ////////
        .onAppear { 
            UIApplication.topViewController()?
               .navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        }
/////// HERE ////////
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                TabView(selection: .constant(0),
                        content: {
                            TestView()
                                .tabItem { Text("test") }
                                .tag(0)
                                .navigationBarTitle("")
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                        })
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working in iOS 15

Comment: Ive got a fix that works also for iOS 15 above.  Make .tabBarHidden false then true when each tab appears.

Answer (score 0):

In the View you want to hide the `NavigationView` use `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to hide it.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

If you don't want the big NavigationView, use `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` to shrink the size, and also keep using `ToolBarItems`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get access to the boolean that sets whether or not you are showing your navigation bar, you can fix this issue.  But its not pleasant - I think there must be a bug behind the issue here.

The `NavigationView` that contains the `TabView` has a modifier that governs if the nav bar shows.  Something like this:

```
NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination:
                                TabBarScreen(domainDependencies: domainDependencies).environmentObject(navState),
                               isActive: $navState.initialNavMainLink) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            //the property here governs hiding of nav bar:
            .navigationBarHidden(navState.initialNavBarHidden)
```

Ive put that property (`initialNavBarHidden`) within my NavState class, which is an object that contains all the nav links etc for my entire app navigation.  That object is placed in the `@environment` so i can use it anywhere.

On the `.onAppear` for each tab, if I set that property to false, and then true, using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter ..` with a short gap between them, then the problem is fixed.  As I say, its a hack, but it works.  I could get nothing else to work after some days looking at this issue.

So I have a function on my navState class like this:

```
func tabBarBugFix() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            self.initialNavBarHidden = false
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.00001) {
                self.initialNavBarHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

And I call it for `onAppear` for each tab page, eg:

```
struct PostPage: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var navState: NavState
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Create a Post")
            .onAppear() {
                navState.tabBarBugFix()
            }
    }
}
```

You get a tiny visual glitch, which is horrible but brief.  As a better fix Im actually going to take my tab bar out of the NavigationView altogether, as thats where the bug happens.

Answer (score 0):

To fix for `iOS 15`, just set 3 properties (***navigationBarTitle***, ***navigationBarBackButtonHidden*** and ***navigationBarHidden***) as below:

```
TabView {
    HomeView()
        .tabItem {
            Text("Home")
        }
        .tag(0)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)

    SettingView()
        .tabItem {
            Text("Setting")
        }
        .tag(1)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

Make sure you don't set these properties inside HomeView() or SettingView(),...

Answer (score -1):

you have already hide the navigation bar with `.navigationBarHidden(true)`. here you are seeing the `safe area` , so you can let your view expand in to the safe area by using `.ignoresSafeArea()`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                
                TabView(selection: .constant(0),
                        content: {
                            TestView()
                                .tabItem { Text("test") }
                                .tag(0)
                                .navigationBarTitle("")
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                                .ignoresSafeArea() //<-here
                        })
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi That's iOS 14 api, I am running on iOS 13. And not that safe area but the navigation bar, check the image on the question above.

Comment: Are you getting this problem only with iOS 13 not with iOS 14? cause I have run on iOS 14 and it gave me this result.

Answer (score -1):

How about the negative padding trick?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TabView {
        List(1 ..< 40, id: \.self) {
          Text("A" + $0.description)
        }.tag(1).navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        List(1 ..< 40, id: \.self) {
          Text("B" + $0.description)
        }.tag(2).navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
      }.padding(.bottom, -50) // <- trick
    }
  }
}
```