# Taking Top Space When Adding Tab Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabbar, side-menu, swiftui-tabview

I am integrating **Side Menu** in my *SwiftUI* app. The *side menu* is working fine. The problem I am getting is I have a **tab bar** at the bottom, and when I open my *side menu* screen, it is taking some space from the top and I am not getting why it is getting that space. This is what I am getting:

[image: simulator]

And when I open **Debug View Hierarchy**, it is showing me this:

[image: Debug Hierarchy]

This is my code for my *home screen*:

```
struct HomeView: View {

@State var menuOpen: Bool = false

var body: some View {

Zstack {
  ZStack {
          HStack {
                                    
               if !self.menuOpen {
                           Button {
                                            
                               print("side menu tapped")
                               self.menuOpen.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                  Image("sideMenuButton")
                                      .resizable()
                                      .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                   }.padding()
                                }
                            Spacer()
                                  
                        }     
                     Text("Home")
                        .font(.custom(Poppins.semiBold.rawValue, size: 17))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(ColorName.appBlue.rawValue))
           }

       ZStack {
                SideMenu(width: 300,
                         isOpen: self.menuOpen,
                         menuClose: self.openMenu)
            }
       }     
      }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

     func openMenu() {
           self.menuOpen.toggle()
      }
}
```

This is working fine when I use it **without** tab bar. Without tab bar it looks like this:

[image: without tab bar]

My code for tab bar controller is:

```
struct TabBarControllerView: View {
    
    @State private var tabSelection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", image: tabSelection == 0 ? ImageName.home.rawValue : ImageName.silverHome.rawValue)
                }
                .tag(0)

          MyAccountView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Claims", image: tabSelection == 1 ? ImageName.claims.rawValue : ImageName.silverClaims.rawValue)
                }
                .tag(1)

     }.accentColor(Color(ColorName.appBlue.rawValue))

 }
}

struct TabBarControllerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBarControllerView()
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why is it getting the top space? I tried **.ignoresSafeArea()** and also gave **padding** in *negative*, it *went* to top but the side menu did not *tapping* because it is getting under that space.

I am been stuck in this for 2 days, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TabView comes with Navigation Bar up top. There is a simple solution by adding `.navigationBarHidden(true)`.

See this post: [SwiftUI how to hide navigation bar with TabView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343963/swiftui-how-to-hide-navigation-bar-with-tabview)

Note: Also in the future give a proper minimum amount of code to reproduce the behavior. Your current code given relies on other components and isn't runnable by itself on a fresh project.

Update:
I created a minimum project to test this and this code works fine with me:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabBarView()
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
                .tag(0)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green)

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        print("side menu tapped")
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    }.padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Given that this code works fine and the issue is not here, minimum working code sample is needed from OP.

Comment: I tried both .navigationBarHidden(true), .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) but it is not working

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet where all the code is in one file, so I can copy paste it to a new project and try out the behavior.

Comment: I have my code in zip. How will I send it to you?

Comment: Just combine the code into one file, remove unnecessary code from the example (like the accentColor) and add that to your original question.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue by using your code too.

Comment: So when you copy paste my code into a new Xcode project you don't get the same end result? What Xcode version are you running? I have 13.3.1

Comment: yes I implemented in a separate project and it is doing the same. My Xcode version is 13.3

Comment: Try to add one more tab then switch tab and see the problem.