# How to create a reusable alert view used across different view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

in the simple language: can we create that alert Box as a reusable method
[image: AlertBox]

i want to made 1 Alert box  in to the function.
like this.

```
// this code has separate file 

import UIKit

struct AlertView {
    public func showAlertBox(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
       }))
    return alert
  }
}
```

and  here is my caller ViewController file code.

```
 @IBAction func submitPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     let alertView = AlertView()
     let alert = alertView.showAlertBox(title: "Hours Added", message: "Hours have been updated")
     alert.present(alert, animated: true) {
         self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         self?.timeSubmitted = true
         self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMyHours", sender: nil)
     }
 }
```

Comment: What does "Can We call 1 alertController into meny viewController in swift" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need alert action to performing `ok` action.

You can modify your code by this

Here are the helper functions.

```
struct AlertView {
    public static func showAlertBox(title: String, message: String, handler: ((UIAlertAction)->Void)?) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: handler))
        return alert
    }
}

extension UIAlertController {
    func present(on viewController: UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        viewController.present(self, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func submitPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        AlertView.showAlertBox(title: "Hours Added", message: "Hours have been updated") { [weak self] action in
            // Okay action code
        }.present(on: self) { [weak self] in
            self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self?.timeSubmitted = true
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMyHours", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

###### Note: self is dismissing so might be your alert is not presenting. You can present your alert on top most view controller. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301729/14733292)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a shared alert controller. I would suggest making it a static method of your struct, or even a global function. It's silly to create an instance of your struct only to invoke a method that doesn't need any instance variables:

```
    public static func alertBox(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
       }))
    return alert
  }
}
```

And then you'd invoke it by saying

```
let alert = AlertView.alertBox(title: "title",message: "message" )
```

(Your function doesn't show the alert, it just creates it. I would therefore suggest naming it `alertBox`, not 'showAlertBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a shared alert controller. What I would suggest is making the `AlertView` struct, a singleton. You can change the struct as follows

```
struct AlertView {
    
    // Shared instance
    static let shared: AlertView = AlertView()

    // Private initializer to prevent creating of new instances
    private init() {}

    public func showAlertBox(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
        }))
        return alert
    }
}
```

By doing so, you will be able to create just one instance of `AlertView` and you have to use that single instance in your program. That way you won't have to create new instances of `AlertView` every time you need to display an alert. You can invoke it using,

```
let alert = AlertView.shared.showAlertBox(title: "Hours Added", message: "Hours have been updated")
```

Edit - You can refer [this](https://medium.com/@nimjea/singleton-class-in-swift-17eef2d01d88) medium article to understand the singleton design patter

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to perform simple encapsulation through extension, and complex encapsulation just loses applicability

example:

```
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        .addActionTitles(titles) { (alertVC, action) in
            let actionIdx = alertVC.actions.firstIndex(of: action)
            DDLog(actionIdx)
        }
        self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion:{})
```

code:

```
public let kTitleSure    = "Yes"
public let kTitleCancell = "No"
/// contentViewController
public let kAlertContentViewController = "contentViewController"

@objc public extension UIAlertController{

    ///add UIAlertAction
    @discardableResult
    func addActionTitles(_ titles: [String]? = [kTitleCancell, kTitleSure], handler: ((UIAlertController, UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
        titles?.forEach({ (string) in
            let style: UIAlertAction.Style = string == kTitleCancell ? .cancel : .default
            self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: string, style: style, handler: { (action) in
                handler?(self, action)
            }))
        })
        return self
    }
    ///add textField
    @discardableResult
    func addTextFieldPlaceholders(_ placeholders: [String]?, handler: ((UITextField) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
        if self.preferredStyle != .alert {
            return self
        }
        placeholders?.forEach({ (string) in
            self.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
                textField.placeholder = string
                handler?(textField)
            }
        })
        return self
    }

    @discardableResult
    func setContent(vc: UIViewController, height: CGFloat) -> Self {
        setValue(vc, forKey: kAlertContentViewController)
        vc.preferredContentSize.height = height
        preferredContentSize.height = height
        return self
    }
}
```

[github](https://github.com/shang1219178163/SwiftExpand/blob/master/SwiftExpand/ios/UIAlertController%2BHelper.swift)