# Swift & Navigation : How do I replace a ViewController and also send some parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation, storyboard

How do I replace a ViewController and also send some parameters?

With the code below, I can only push another ViewController into my current Navigation Stack.
Can we just pop and push another one immediately? Or is there an official to replace for good? Please kindly show me. Thank you.

Perform Segue

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToNewViewController", sender: self)
```

Prepare Segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! NewViewController
        destinationVC.params = params
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a navigation controller as your app window root , then you can manage all `viewControllers`

```
var vcs = self.navigationController!.viewControllers // get all vcs
vcs = vcs.dropLast() // remove last vc
let vc = // create new VC
vcs.append(vc) // append it
```

Then alter that array and set it back like this

```
self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(vcs,animated:true)
```

**OR**

You can get the top presented vc with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller) , then add a method to that vc to do the data replacement and refresh of your UI

Comment: Then I can just use `Prepare Segue` to pass the `parameters`? Could you me a full code?

Comment: Above 2 ways is when you need to do the altering so it has no segue just a management of the presented vcs either pop/push or get the top and alter it , don't confuse this with showing the vc

Comment: I'm new to iOS dev. Could you give me the full code?

Comment: @PunreachRany you may accept answer if helped

Comment: it looks like I have replaced the screen. But the storyboard UI associated with the ViewController didn't show up. In other words, it showed a black screen