# iOS swift screen rotation issue

Tags: ios, swift

I change view controller from one to other. The phone was in Landscape orientation when first controller was active. Second controller supports only portrait orientation. When it becomes active it for a moment has landscape orientation, so it's content is drawn for landscape orientation also. Then view controller rotates to portrait orientation, but the redrawing of the content doesn't happens.

In `viewWillTransition` I call `view.setNeedsDisplay()` but that doesn't help too.

To solve the problem I made `initUI` function which is called in `viewDidLoad` only if main window is in portrait orientation. In other case I call `initUI` in  `viewWillTransition`.

I want to know what code should I write in such standard situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the **SecondViewController** to only **portrait**. You can use a method of **AppDelegate**.
In that method you can check the current TopViewController, and based on that you can return the orientation.

Please check the code below.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)!.children.last!.isKind(of: SecondViewController.self){
        return .portrait
    }else{
        return .all
    }
}
```

To get the TopViewController you can use this extension:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50656239/5973760

Comment: Second view controller already restricted to portrait orientation. But it loads for a short time in landscape orientation, then rotates.