# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, presentviewcontroller

In iOS <= 7, directly after calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` would result in `presentedViewController` being `nil`.
In iOS 8, `presentedViewController` still points to the presented viewcontroller, right until the completion block is executed.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    //self.presentedViewController is nil
}];
//self.presentedViewController is nil on iOS 7, but not nil on iOS 8
```

So in iOS 8 we cannot rely on the property `presentedViewController` in order to find out which viewcontroller is currently the top visible viewcontroller.

In iOS 8, alerts need to be presented onto a viewcontroller (which [poses another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419458/show-uialertcontroller-if-already-showing-an-alert)). They will not show if the viewcontroller we try to present on already presents a viewcontroller.

If I just dismissed my presented viewcontroller and show a `UIAlertController` on the currently top visible viewcontroller (by recursively searching for the last `presentedViewController`), then it will of course not show but log an error message: "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

1. Is this a bug in iOS 8 or just the new way?
2. How can I find out the viewcontroller I can present my `UIALertController` on?

Comment: `isBeingDismissed` helps a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to find out which viewcontroller I can present the alert upon:

```
@implementation UIViewController (visibleViewController)

- (UIViewController *)my_visibleViewController {

    if ([self isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        // do not use method visibleViewController as the presentedViewController could beingDismissed
        return [[(UINavigationController *)self topViewController] my_visibleViewController];
    }

    if ([self isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        return [[(UITabBarController *)self selectedViewController] my_visibleViewController];
    }

    if (self.presentedViewController == nil || self.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed) {
        return self;
    }

    return [self.presentedViewController my_visibleViewController];
}

@end

// To show a UIAlertController, present on the following viewcontroller:
UIViewController *visibleViewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController my_visibleViewController];
```

Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func visibleViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        guard !(self is UINavigationController) else {
            let navVC = self as! UINavigationController
            return navVC.topViewController?.visibleViewController()
        }

        guard !(self is UITabBarController) else {
            let tabVC = self as! UITabBarController
            return tabVC.selectedViewController?.visibleViewController()
        }

        if self.presentedViewController == nil || 
           self.presentedViewController!.isBeingDismissed {
            return self
        }

        return self.presentedViewController?.visibleViewController()
    }
}
```