# What is the best way to check if a UIAlertController is already presenting?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I have a tableview which, when loaded, each cell could possibly return an NSError, which I have chosen to display in a UIAlertController.  Problem is I get this error in the console if multiple errors are returned.

> Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController: 0x14e64cb00  on MessagesMasterVC: 0x14e53d800 which is already presenting (null)

Ideally, I would ideally like to handle this in my UIAlertController extension method.

```
class func simpleAlertWithMessage(message: String!) -> UIAlertController {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    return alertController
}
```

Based on matt's answer, I changed the extension to a UIViewController extension, its much cleaner and saves lots of presentViewController code.

```
    func showSimpleAlertWithMessage(message: String!) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(cancel)

    if self.presentedViewController == nil {
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your updated code.

Comment: I also moved the rest of the code (three lines to setup the UIAlertController) into the If statement, because it was still giving the following error (Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior)

Comment: I would like to refer the solution on below link, please check

http://stackoverflow.com/a/39994115/1872233

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It is not the UIAlertController that is "already presenting", it is MessagesMasterVC. A view controller can only present one other view controller at a time. Hence the error message.

In other words, if you have told a view controller to `presentViewController:...`, you cannot do that again until the presented view controller has been dismissed.

You can ask the MessagesMasterVC whether it is already presenting a view controller by examining its `presentedViewController`. If not `nil`, do not tell it to `presentViewController:...` - it is already presenting a view controller.

Comment: If controller A presents controller B,  and then B wants to present UIAlertController,  would that work?   I'm having the same error and I can't figure if B is already presenting something I don't know of,  or if the problem is because B is being presented by A

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Ask that as a new question!

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Hi, I have the same problem now, have you made a new question for it? or where you able to solve it? if yes, how?

Answer (score 32):

```
if ([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {

      // UIAlertController is presenting.Here

}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not a great answer due to lacking explanation, but the method helped me a lot - problem was I had more than one event calling my code to present a `UIAlertController` firing in short succession. Check for this if you have a similar problem.

Answer (score 11):

Well, the suggested solutions above has an essential problem from my point of view:

If you ask your ViewController, whether the attribute 'presentedViewController' is nil and the answer is false, you can't come to the conclusion, that your UIAlertController is already presented. It could be any presented ViewController, e.g. a popOver. So my suggestion to surely check, whether the Alert is already on the screen is the following (cast the presentedViewController as a UIAlertController):

```
if self.presentedViewController == nil {
   // do your presentation of the UIAlertController
   // ...
} else {
   // either the Alert is already presented, or any other view controller
   // is active (e.g. a PopOver)
   // ...

   let thePresentedVC : UIViewController? = self.presentedViewController as UIViewController?

   if thePresentedVC != nil {
      if let thePresentedVCAsAlertController : UIAlertController = thePresentedVC as? UIAlertController {
         // nothing to do , AlertController already active
         // ...
         print("Alert not necessary, already on the screen !")

      } else {
         // there is another ViewController presented
         // but it is not an UIAlertController, so do 
         // your UIAlertController-Presentation with 
         // this (presented) ViewController
         // ...
         thePresentedVC!.presentViewController(...)

         print("Alert comes up via another presented VC, e.g. a PopOver")
      }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution I use in Swift 3.  It is a function that shows an alert to the user, and if you call it multiple times before the user has dismissed the alert, it will add the new alert text to the alert that's already being presented.  If some other view is being presented, the alert will not appear.  Not all will agree with that behavior, but it works well for simple situations.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(_ msg: String, title: String = "") {
        if let currentAlert = self.presentedViewController as? UIAlertController {
            currentAlert.message = (currentAlert.message ?? "") + "\n\nUpdate:\(title): \(msg)"
            return
        }

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this is what I needed. It is works in iOS 13 too.

Answer (score 5):

> **Swift 4.2+ Answer**

```
if UIApplication.topViewController()!.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self) { 
            print("UIAlertController is presented")}
```

**For those who don't know how to get top most Viewcontroller**

```
extension UIApplication {


public class func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    return base
}}
```

> **Swift 5+ Answer**
>   *'keyWindow'* was deprecated in iOS 13.0 
>   *suggested edit*

```
if UIApplication.topViewController()!.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self) { 
            print("UIAlertController is presented")}
```

**For those who don't know how to get top most Viewcontroller**

```
extension UIApplication {


public class func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    return base
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply check if any view controller is presented.

if presented then check if it is kind of UIAlertController .

```
    id alert = self.presentedViewController;

    if (alert && [alert isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) 
      {
           *// YES UIAlertController is already presented*
      }
    else
       {
        // UIAlertController is not presented OR visible.
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can test - in a single line - if an alert is already presented:

```
if self.presentedViewController as? UIAlertController != nil {
    print ("alert already presented")
}
```

Comment: You could explain the code in your answer. Or how it adds relevant information when there is already an accepted or highly rated answer Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This category can auto-manage all the modal controllers include of UIAlertController.

[UIViewController+JCPresentQueue.h](https://github.com/HJaycee/JCAlertController/blob/master/JCAlertController/JCAlertController/Category/UIViewController%2BJCPresentQueue.h)

Answer (score 0):

I used that to detect and remove and alert.

First we create an alert with following function.

```
 var yourAlert :UIAlertController!

 func useYouAlert (header: String, info:String){


    yourAlert = UIAlertController(title:header as String, message: info as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)



    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: self.langText[62]as String, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("OK") 

    }


    yourAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(yourAlert.addAction, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And in some other part of your code

```
    if yourAlert != nil {

      yourAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest Swift language you can use following:

```
var alert = presentedViewController

if alert != nil && (alert is UIAlertController) {
    // YES UIAlertController is already presented*
} else {
    // UIAlertController is not presented OR visible.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the current controller and present the alert controller like

```
 func alert(_ message:String) {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
  self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  self.present(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to create a queue to stack the UIAlertController requests.

```
NSMutableArray *errorMessagesToShow; // in @interface
errorMessagesToShow=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  // in init

-(void)showError:(NSString *)theErrorMessage{
    if(theErrorMessage.length>0){
        [errorMessagesToShow addObject:theErrorMessage];
        [self showError1];
    }
}
-(void)showError1{
    NSString *theErrorMessage;
    if([errorMessagesToShow count]==0)return; // queue finished

    UIViewController* parentController =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].rootViewController;
    while( parentController.presentedViewController &&
      parentController != parentController.presentedViewController ){
        parentController = parentController.presentedViewController;
    }
    if([parentController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])return;  // busy

    // construct the alert using [errorMessagesToShow objectAtIndex:0]
    //  add to each UIAlertAction completionHandler [self showError1];
    //   then

    [errorMessagesToShow removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [parentController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply dismiss the current controller and present the one you want
i.e.

`self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

`self.displayAlertController()`