# How do I set a NSTimer to stop if a certain action is running?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a popup in a custom view controller that is presented after 1 minute thanks to my `NSTimer`.

My `NSTimer` code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f
                                 target:self selector:@selector(methodB:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`
```

The method that reveals the popup

```
- (void) methodB:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    //Do calculations.
    [self showPopupWithStyle:CNPPopupStyleFullscreen];
}
```

I'm trying to set the `NSTimer` to stop running if the `[self showPopupWithStyle:CNPPopupStyleFullscreen];` is currently open, running or active.

Then I would like to start the `NSTimer` back up again if the popup view controller is NOT open, running or active.

Any help, samples or examples would be greatly appreciated!

My project is written in Objective-C.

EDIT:

I tried the answers in the suggested "possibly similar" answer and it doesn't seem to work for what I am doing. How do I stop `NSTimer`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: check if a UIAlertView is showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528929/iphone-sdk-check-if-a-uialertview-is-showing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CNPPopupController *popupController;
- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end

NSTimer *_timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (!_timer) {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
}


}

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

if ([_timer isValid]) {
    [self showPopupWithStyle:CNPPopupStyleFullscreen];
    [_timer invalidate];
}
_timer = nil;
    NSLog(@"ping");
}
```

If you want to restart the timer just add this code where you'd like the action to start back up.

```
if (!_timer) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    }
```

Hope this helps! :)