# react native ios alert overriding each other

Tags: ios, react-native, uialertview

I am using `Alert.alert()` for displaying alert in react native ios. 
Problem i am facing is that if tow alert of same message appears they appear one above the other.

While in android second alert appear after dismissing the first one.

Anyway to make it behave like android in ios?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a certain state boolean to check if `alert` is visible or not such as

```
  state = {
    alertBoxVisible: false,
  }

  onAlertShow = () => {
    if(!this.state.alertBoxVisible) {
      this.setState({alertBoxVisible: true}, () => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Alert Title',
          'My Alert Msg',
          [
            {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.setState({alertBoxVisible: false})},
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        )
      })
    }
  }
```

and use `async await` to chain the functions that call the `onAlertShow` such as

```
onPress={async () => {
  await this.onAlertShow()
  await this.onAlertShow()
}}
```

Comment: Good workaround, but i'm expecting solution which doesn't include dealing with state. Can't something be done by passing some props to native alertview?

Comment: The native solution has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228568/6606831) by checking the visibility of the `AlertBox`. I don't know about native code but you can try implementing one of these solutions